# Codesnippet for sorting collection<T> based on a comma-separated string value

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting

In my code I use a `collection<T>` as binding source for different controls (WPF/C#). The collection is created from the system every time the application loads. I don't have control on the collection and its order (items within the collection) are randomly for every launch of the app.

For UI reasons I need to allow to sort the collection, display it in a listview and keep the sorting when modified by the user (moveup and movedown buttons). Therefore my Idea was simple. I simply write the items comma-separated into a hidden string variable eg. `"itemX,ItemY,ItemZ"`.

Now I need a function that sorts the collection based on the string. I was thinking of a few foreach loops, but I am sure there is a better way of sorting the collection.

- sort the Items within `collection<t>` in the same order as represented by the string.

  ```
  string correctItemOrder = "Application5, Application2, Application4, Application3".
  ```

`Collection<T>` has items with just the property name (e.g. `"Applicaton3"`) but is sorted randomly. I want to sort the collection in the same order as the string.

`T` is an interface an I can access a property `"Name"` that has the value that is stored in the string eg. "ItemX".

Any cool snippets/functions?

Thanks

Comment: Any sample input and expected output?

Comment: string correctItemOrder = "Application5, Application2, Application4, Application3". Collection<T> has Items with just the Property Name (e.g. "Applicaton3") but is sorted ranomly. I want to sort the collection in the same order as the string.

Comment: Edit the question with this

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need it sorted? This approach seems a little strange to me, and would be tricky to maintain if the application is ever altered to have more/fewer controls.

Comment: `Collection<T>`? What is that `T` string ?

Comment: I know its a bit strange, but in UI the order of the items (only for the user) is important. As the collection is the binding source for many controls, i need to sort that collection. Othwerwise I could easly maintain my own list. I know its tricky, but its the only way...would be great if you could see it as a generic request. Should be some cool and fast sorting function based on a input parameter (the string) - thx

Comment: T is of type IDataItem. I can access it dataItem["Name"].ToString(). Result is e.g. "Applicaton5"

Comment: That what you want: [Dynamic SQL-like Linq OrderBy Extension](http://aonnull.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/dynamic-sql-like-linq-orderby-extension.html)

Comment: thanks. It^s a lot of code :-) Maybe there is something "smaller" :-) I give it a try

Comment: @YairNevet Why not use LINQ's built-in OrderBy extension (which takes delegates), rather than a wrapper which parses a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of ideas...

Either way, you'll want your "item order string" as an array, so...

```
var sortOrder = correctItemOrder.Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Then one option is to order your collection by the order of items in sortOrder (meaning you have to traverse through half of sortOrder, on average, for each element in your collection):

```
var sortedCollection = new Collection<T>(collection.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(sortOrder, x.Name)).ToList());
```

Another option is to create a dictionary of Name => item, then traverse sortOrder, selecting items from this dictionary as you go...

```
var dict = collection.ToDictionary(x => x.Name);
var sortedCollection = new Collection<T>(sortOrder.Select(x => dict[x]).ToList());
```

It's worth noting that if new items are added to the collection, but not sortOrder, the first snippet will place them at the start of the collection, whereas the second one will discard them entirely. Similarly if items are present in sortOrder but not the collection, the first snippet will ignore them, whereas the second one will throw an exception.

EDIT:

The third option, of course, is to create dictionary from sortOrder, and use that.

```
var dict = sortOrder.Select((x, i) => new { x, i }).ToDictionary(x => x.x, x => x.i);
var sortedCollection = new Collection<T>(collection.OrderBy(x => dict[x.Name]).ToList());
```

EDIT2:

As Enigmativity has pointed out, using lookups instead of dictionaries allows you to handle the cases where dictionary keys are missing very neatly.

The last example using this technique:

```
var lookup = sortOrder.Select((x, i) => new {x, i}).ToLookup(x => x.x, x => x.i);
var sortedCollection = new Collection<T>(collection.OrderBy(x => lookup[x.Name].DefaultIfEmpty(Int32.MaxValue).First()).ToList());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a comparer like this should do the job:

```
public interface INamed {
   string Name {get;}
}

public class CustomComparer : Comparer<INamed> {

        Dictionary<string, int> hash;

        public CustomComparer( ) {
           var tokens = "Application5, Application2, Application4, Application3"
                        .Split( ',' )
                        .Select( s => s.Trim( ) )
                        .ToArray( );
           hash = Enumerable.Range(0, tokens.Length)
                            .ToDictionary( i => tokens[i]  );
        }

        public override int Compare( INamed x, INamed y ) {
            return hash[x.Name] - hash[y.Name];
        }

        public static readonly CustomComparer Default = new CustomComparer();
    }
```

EDIT: I see that Collection has not order by itself, so is needed to build a wrapper

```
  class SortableCollection<T> : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>
  {
    public SortableCollection() : this(new List<T>()) {}
    public SortableCollection(List<T> list) : base(list) {}
    public virtual void Sort() { ((List<T>)Items).Sort(); }
  }

  class CustomSortableCollection<T> : SortableCollection<T> where T: INamed
  {
    public override void Sort() { 
       ((List<INamed>)Items).Sort(CustomComparer.Default); 
    }
  }
```

This way you can sort the colection when you need it doing:

```
     your_collection.Sort();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var rank =
    correctItemOrder
        .Split(',')
        .Select((x, n) => new { x = x.Trim(), n, })
        .ToLookup(z => z.x, z => z.x);

var query =
    from i in items
    orderby rank[i.Name]
        .DefaultIfEmpty(int.MaxValue)
        .First()
    select i;
```

This handles missing values in the `correctItemOrder` string too.